# SQL Declare variable inside SELECT statement

Tags: sql, oracle

Trying to run a SELECT statement to create a view that performs some calculations.

I want to use the calculated value in another field without having to calculate again

*Shape field stores geographical data, and sde.st_y/x is a function that returns the lat/long of the shape*

Example :

```
SELECT
    t.shape AS "Shape",
    t.code AS "GeocodeTo",
    sde.st_x(t.shape) AS "Longitude_decimal",
    --The following field calculates sde.st_x again unnecesairly
    TRUNC(ABS(sde.st_x(t.shape)) as "Absolute"         
FROM
    towers t
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to call function twice then try this

```
select "Shape","GeocodeTo",TRUNC(ABS(Longitude_decimal)) 
from 
(
SELECT
    t.shape AS "Shape",
    t.code AS "GeocodeTo",
    sde.st_x(t.shape) AS "Longitude_decimal"
FROM
    towers t
) a
```

But I think Oracle will be smart enough to call the function only once in your original query though you call it twice

Answer (score 1):

Call the function in subquery and reuse the value outside:

```
SELECT "Shape",
  "GeocodeTo",
  "Longitude_decimal",
  TRUNC(ABS("Longitude_decimal") AS "Absolute"
FROM
  (SELECT t.shape     AS "Shape",
    t.code            AS "GeocodeTo",
    sde.st_x(t.shape) AS "Longitude_decimal",
  FROM towers t
  );
```